# Clear a String after a certain character

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, slice

I get this path `/system/papers/articles/000/000/024/original/data.png?1404191431` using paperclip.But as you can after the extension(.png) I get a number,I have no idea why..
So I would like to clear all text after the `.png`including the **?**.

How do I do it in ruby?

The reason I need that link is because I need to add metadata to it using ImageMagick which currently I am not able to do cause of the random number which comes.

Also if possible I would like to know why does that number get printed by paperclip cause from what I see,the number doesnt get saved in the database nor does it save to the image name..

Comment: I think it's for browser caching (ie if the picture gets changed, the number gets updated and thus the browser grabs the new copy instead of caching the old version)

Comment: How do you get this path? Maybe there's another method that doesn't add the number.

Comment: @Stefan  my process goes like this...I have a form along with an image which I crop.all this data is sent to the database along with the path  .All this happens in create action,after the line if `@record.valid @record.save` I try to get the path of image stored using @record.article.url.

Comment: @Stefan the reason I am removing the number is because rmmagick throws some encoding error for the link.I am trying to add metadata to the image...but I am stuck on that now

Comment: @Santino'Sonny'Corleone If you need the file system path, use `@record.article.path` instead.

Comment: @Stefan thnx for that.if u could help with this it wud be great.
`image = Magick::Image.new(1, 1)    
      image['keywords'] = 'Testing,JS,jquery,hello world'
      image.write(image_path)`  the image path I am getting as you said but when I check the image in the folder(original) it shows me a blank image(white image) but in the thumb and medium folder I can see the image..What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Santino'Sonny'Corleone that seems to be a different problem, please post a separate question including further details.

Comment: @Stefan fine..thnx for the previous help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `[]` and a regular expression to "assign" an empty string over the matched pattern.

```
str = '/system/papers/articles/000/000/024/original/data.png?1404191431'

str[/\?\d+$/] = ''
```

The number is likely added for cache-busting purposes.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [`URI`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html) class:

```
require 'uri'

str = '/system/papers/articles/000/000/024/original/data.png?1404191431'

URI.parse(str).path
#=> "/system/papers/articles/000/000/024/original/data.png"
```

Regarding your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24503003/clear-a-string-after-a-certain-character/24503761?noredirect=1#comment37935375_24503003):

> ... I try to get the path of image stored using `@record.article.url`

You can get the file's absolute path with `.path` instead of `.url`:

```
@record.article.path
#=> "/path/to/project/public/system/papers/articles/000/000/024/original/data.png"
```

Comment: Ahh.. Just pasted and about to click on *post your answer*... :-) +1

Comment: Are you following [*Are we dying?*](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4486783#new). I am scared about it... :-(

Answer (score 2):

```
"/system/papers/articles/000/000/024/original/data.png?1404191431"
.split("?").first
```